# How to change settings of a printer without admin permissions - python

Tags: python, windows, printing

I've been sitting on this problem for a while now and still can't wrap my head around it. I have the code below but I can't even really test it because I do not have access to administrator permissions. Whenever I try the win32print.SetPrinter function I get an "Access Denied" error which I can fix by entering the console as admin but the program needs to run without admin permissions when it's done. There obviously are programs that can print without admin permissions so there has to be a way.

```py
file_path = 'path\\test.ps'
printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
file_handle = open(file_path, 'rb')
printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
info = win32print.GetPrinter(printer_handle, 2)["pDevMode"]


if (win32print.DocumentProperties(0, printer_handle, printer_name, info, info, 5) == 1):
    win32print.SetPrinter(printer_handle, 2, info, 0)
    job = win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer_handle,1,("postscripttest",None,"RAW"))
    print(win32print.GetJob(printer_handle, job))
    win32print.WritePrinter(printer_handle,file_handle.read())
    win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer_handle)
    win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)
else:
    print("Process Cancled")
```

I am a bit lost as to where I could look. First I was really happy when win32print.DocumentProperties with mode 5 gave me an interface where I could set the printer options, which is exactly what I need, and it also saved the changes in "info", a DevMode object. However, I can't think of another way to actually "Save" those settings than with SetPrinter. And as I said before, SetPrinter requires Admin perms, unless there is a different way to use it that I don't know of.

For a TL;DR: I need to be able to change the printer settings for one printer job without admin permissions. Just a simple one page printer job from a postscript file where I can set the options for how the printer is supposed to print beforehand.

Any help is highly appreciated. It really seems like there is practically nobody who knows their stuff with python and printers.

Answer (score -1):

To change the settings of a printer job without modifying the actual printer settings, you'd want to use the DocumentProperties method with mode DM_PROMPT to let the user select the properties. Then, you can utilize the changed properties when calling the StartDocPrinter method. This should not require admin permissions, as you are only altering the settings for a single job and not the printer itself.

You can try

1. Use the DocumentProperties method with the DM_PROMPT mode (which is
   4) to display the printer's property dialog. This allows users to
   modify the properties for a single job.
2. The modified pDevMode object
   is then used when sending the job to the printer, so that the job is
   printed with the modified properties.

Updated version of your script:

```
import win32print
import win32con

# File and printer info
file_path = 'path\\test.ps'
printer_name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()

# Get a handle to the printer
printer_handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

# Get the current printer settings
info = win32print.GetPrinter(printer_handle, 2)["pDevMode"]

# Display the printer property dialog
if (win32print.DocumentProperties(0, printer_handle, printer_name, info, info, win32con.DM_PROMPT) == win32con.IDOK):
    # Start the print job with the modified settings
    job = win32print.StartDocPrinter(printer_handle, 1, ("postscripttest", None, "RAW"))
    
    # Read the file and send it to the printer
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_handle:
        win32print.WritePrinter(printer_handle, file_handle.read())
    
    # End the print job
    win32print.EndDocPrinter(printer_handle)

else:
    print("Process Canceled")

# Close the printer handle
win32print.ClosePrinter(printer_handle)
```

Comment: Did you test this and did it work for you? I tried this before and changed the paper to grayscale but it didn't work. Nothing changed sadly. If it worked for you, any idea what could be the issue for me?

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that I have to use the "info" for something but I don't know where I could use it. StartDocPrinter doesn't really accept a parameter like that and the only thing I found that it could be used for would be SetPrinter. The solution is probably a function that accepts the devmode as parameter and doesn't need admin perms like SetPrinter so that it only affects a job and not the printer itself